# Order preserving minimal perfect hash functions

Tags: c++, hash

I want to implement an OPMPH function for the words in a dictionary in C++. How do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at these papers?

- http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.84.4018&rep=rep1&type=pdf
- http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(92)90220-P (the short form link that leads to a very  long link at http://www.sciencedirect.com/)
- http://eprints.cs.vt.edu/archive/00000248/01/TR-91-01.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Limit your word length to 6 letters or less and you might be able to make it work.  Not very practical.

Answer (score 1):

If you need alphabetical order use a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or a [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_deterministic_finite_automaton) (like I recommended in your last question). For an order besides alphabetic I would use a binary tree (std::map in C++ is implemented with a red-black tree usually).

Implementing an order preserving hash container sounds like the mother of all early optimizations.